# vb.net auto detect dependency files for wix 3.7

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, deployment, wix

I am in the process of learning WIX all thanks to MS for removing such a nice tool (vdproj) from the latest versions of visual studio.

I have come to know that I can add my files (and dlls) to distribute in WIX using that  tag. It is OK. But in vdproj it was very easy to add all files. I just need to right click in file view, and select 'add project output'. This was enough to add dozen of files that were required for my application. In visual studio 2012, and using WIX 3.7, what options do I have to automatically list all those dlls that are required by my application?

Comment: "removing such a nice tool (vdproj)" - man you have made a cardinal sin by mentioning the quoted sentence. Fellow developers "forgive him, for he doesn't not know what he is saying"

Comment: Jokes apart, you can try InstallShield it has better IDE integration with VS. You can also try the WIX DARK.exe tool, it will help you create the WXS script from an MSI.

Comment: What! InstallShield :O but when I started learning about the vdproj alternatives, I read the user reviews about IS and WIX both... and it was them crying 'IS is just a crap' :P not ME!!... anyway, I've no MSI.. I've just a VB solution with a project in it.. And I can manually list all files (in wix) that are required. I was just interested to know if there is some tool that can automate that process for me...

Comment: I didnt say IS is better, just that it has better IDE integration :) What about your old MSI/installer created with vdproj? You can use that as well to create the wxs script using dark.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic method that could be written that wouldn't require you to remove some items and redirect some items to other folders. In the simple case, you wouldn't need an automatic method anyway.

In your WiX Setup project, add a reference to each project you want to include the output from. In the properties for a reference, set Harvest to True and Project Output Groups as desired.

Because project harvesting doesn't work in some corner cases, it is disabled by default. You must enable it in your project file. (See the references.)

Build and you will have ComponentGroups generated for your harvested projects. The script file is in the obj folder (since it's not a file you want to keep in source control).

For example, for the project `ConsoleApplication1`, add a `ConsoleApplication1.Binaries` ComponentGroupRef to a Feature. By default, all such components are placed into INSTALLFOLDER. If you want them elsewhere, you can change the ItemGroup metatdata or one of the properties that affect the HavestProjects target.

Unless you have many project references that change often, there is no need to automate this.

References: WiX.chm

- HarvestProjects Target
- Using Project References and Variables